# class_name not working through has_many association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, `Agent` and `AgentCommand` and this is how the association looks in the models:

```
# models/agent.rb
has_many agent_commands, foreign_key: "agent_id", class_name: "Task"
```

.

```
# models/agent_command.rb
belongs_to :agent
```

However, when I try to call `Agent.first.commands`, I receive this error:

```
2.5.1 :002 > Agent.first.tasks
  Agent Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "agents".* FROM "agents" ORDER BY "agents"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):2
NoMethodError (undefined method `tasks' for #<Agent:0x00007fcc005c2960>)
Did you mean?  company
```

Here's what the migration files for both look like:

```
# db/migrations/date_create_agent_commands.rb
class CreateAgentCommands < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :agent_commands do |t|
      t.belongs_to :agent
      t.text :command
      t.boolean :completed, :default => false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
# db/migrations/date_create_agents.rb
class CreateAgents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :agents do |t|
      t.references :company
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Not quite sure why this isn't working as I thought I remember doing this in the past. Just simply trying to be able to call the model `AgentCommand` from `Agent` through the alias `Task` so that I can use `Agent.first.tasks` and see a list of `agent_commands`

Currently using Rails 5.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out. Apparently I have:

`has_many agent_commands, class_name: "Task"`

when it actually should be the other way around

`has_many :tasks, class_name: "AgentCommand"`

After making this change, it worked as expected.